# How to store select results in mysql?

Tags: mysql

In mysql, I have a trigger which checks for collisions, and updates the hp value of rows that have a collision. I also set a boolean value of the projectile to be true to mean that it should be deleted later. But I seem to do something twice that I would rather done once.

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE TRIGGER checkcollision2 BEFORE UPDATE ON projectiles 
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
    SET @unit_size:=25;

    IF (SELECT count(*) FROM players WHERE wolf=1 AND NEW.x>=x AND NEW.x<=x+@unit_size AND NEW.y>=y AND NEW.y<=y+@unit_size)>0 THEN 
        SET NEW.deleted=1; 
        UPDATE players SET hp=hp-NEW.dmg WHERE wolf=1 AND NEW.x>=x AND NEW.x<=x+@unit_size AND NEW.y>=y AND NEW.y<=y+@unit_size; 
    END IF; 

END;//  
DELIMITER ;
```

In the above, I do a select which gives me the number of rows that have a collision. Then below I do the same query because I want to update those same rows. I could have just done the update, but I only want to do the `SET NEW.deleted=1;` if there was at least 1 row affected. Im not sure how to do that if I only keep the update statement.

Does anyone know of a batter way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the `NEW.deleted` value based on the number of rows affected on `update` then you can use `ROW_COUNT()` to check the number of rows affected.

**Example**:

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE TRIGGER checkcollision2 BEFORE UPDATE ON projectiles 
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
    SET custom_unit_size := 25;

    UPDATE players 
       SET hp = hp - NEW.dmg 
     WHERE wolf   = 1 
       AND NEW.x >= x 
       AND NEW.x <= x + custom_unit_size 
       AND NEW.y >= y 
       AND NEW.y <= y + custom_unit_size; 

    IF ROW_COUNT() > 0 THEN
        SET NEW.deleted = 1;
    END IF;
END;
//  

DELIMITER ;
```

**Refer to**:

- [***ROW_COUNT()***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count)

  - returns the number of rows changed, deleted, or inserted by the last statement if it was an UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT. For other statements, the value may not be meaningful.